# Create dialog over existing page, php-ajax query success, jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

My site has 'dynamic' content, with 'static' nav-buttons replacing only a certain div contents when clicked.

I am successfully getting my php/ajax results back in a dialog box, but I can not understand how to create this dialog *over* my current page.

The result of my current code is that the whole "search.html" is replaced with this new page, that opens a dialog (which is almost what I want). This results in the new-pages background being white, with the results displayed in a dialog over-top.

(This all happens inside a div in my 'index.php')

What I am trying to do is keep my initial page *behind* the dialog box.

I have tried creating a 'dialog' object in the javascript, as some research suggested might work, and then call an .dialog('open') on it. This resulted in an "open is not a function" error (paraphrased).

Further research indicated that JQM dialog's are not the same as JQ UI Dialogs. This is where I got stumped, then tried the 'solution' I am at now.

My 'search.html' (which is loaded in a div inside my index page):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- Removed class="main" -->
     <div  data-role="content" id="main">
        <div id="holder">
           <h1>Search</h1>
           <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="center">
              <form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" onsubmit="return false;">
                 <div id="term">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain" data-mini="true">

                          <input type="radio" name="termChoice" id="term1" value="1"/>
                             <label for="term1">Term 1</label>
                          <input type="radio" name="termChoice" id="term2" value="2" />
                             <label for="term2">Term 2</label>
                          <input type="radio" name="termChoice" id="term3" value="3" />
                             <label for="term3">Term 3</label>
                          <input type="radio" name="termChoice" id="term4" value="4" />
                             <label for="term4">Term 4</label>
                        </fieldset>
                 </div>                                                    
                 <p/>
                 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain">                           
                    <select id="courseSelect" name="courseSelect">
                       <option value="null">Select Course</option>
                    </select> 
                 </fieldset>
                 <p />
                 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain">
                          <input type="radio" name="type" value="lec" id="lec"/>
                             <label for="lec">Lecture</label>
                          <input type="radio" name="type" value="lab" id="lab">
                             <label for="lab">Lab</label>
                          <input type="radio" name="type" value="*" id="both" checked="checked">
                             <label for="both">Both</label>
                 </fieldset>
                 <input type="range" name="numberSlider" id="numberSlider" value="0" min="0" max="35" />
                 <p/>
                 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <input type="submit" value="Go">
                 </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
            <p style="font-size:9px"><i>Note: Zero ('0') on slider indicates *All* lab/lecture numbers.</i></p>
        </div>
     </div>

  <script src="./scripts/searchGo.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/dynamicSelect.js" />
  </body>
  </html>
```

My "searchGo.js":

```
  $(document).ready(function() {    
      $("#searchForm").submit(function(e)
         {
           e.preventDefault();

           var term = document.forms["searchForm"]["termChoice"].value;

           if(term==null || term=="")
           {
              alert("Select Term and Course.");
              return false;
           } else {         
              var formData = $("#searchForm").serialize();
              var trimmedFormData = $.trim(formData);

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "./scripts/search_result.php",
               data: trimmedFormData,
               success: function(data){
                 $("#main").html(data).dialog().trigger('create');       
                 $(this).enhanceWithin();
               }
           });
        }
     });
  });
```

I realize that $(document).ready(function() {}); is not to be used in jQuery Mobile. Though incorrect, the site is functioning alright, and I am quite sure it has nothing to do with the issue I am currently trying to solve.

Since I am loading an entire .html/.php file *inside* a div in my 'index.php', using ' div data-role="page" ' in my search_result.php (loaded after ajax success) is having no affect.

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

I'm new to AJAX, jQuery/jQuery Mobile, and have no idea how to get the result I am looking for.

All I want is to have the 'search_result.php' ("data") loaded in a dialog that opens *on-top* of my "search.html" page...

Sorry for all the code/long post.

Cheers...

Comment: Why don't you just use a large popup? You will get same thing, you can even set opacity to popup overlay div so it looks more like real dialog. One other thing, dialog is deprecated so better use this popup solution. If this is something  you need I will create you a working example.

Comment: Cudos on great question, people usually don't know how to post a good question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I might implement a large pop-up? I don't know how, but I haven't heard of them before... Also, thanks for quick response. Much appreciated

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/45V7G/1/ I made it from my older example, just click Add Popup. Popup can hold everything just like classic jQuery Mobile page, including header and footer

Comment: Amazing. At quick glance-over of your example, I am confident I can get this to work how I need.
Life saver! =P
(Will *try* and add an 'answer' when successfully implemented)

Comment: Could you take a look at my 'edit' in my OP... maybe give me a pointer as to why nothing is showing up?
Don't get any errors, and Network appears to be loading the function call. Yet nothing appears to change (IE, no popup).. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Np but I'll do it when I wake up tomorrow.

Comment: (Know you're not supposed to chat in comments, but...)
Never mind, man! I over-wrote my own-typing with a copy-paste of your code, and it works fine -.-'
I hope it's alright that I use your code as a template for this project.
Your insight was extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same problem, here is a solution:

Following @Gajotres suggestion, and example, my code looks like this.

It is achieving my desired results; a pop-up appearing *over* the current page, with the 'data' retrieved from the PHP query.

My new "searchGo.js":

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  

      $("#searchForm").submit(function(e)
         {
           e.preventDefault();

           var term = document.forms["searchForm"]["termChoice"].value;

           var closeBtn = $('<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>').button();

           if(term==null || term=="")
           {
              alert("Select Term and Course.");
              return false;
           } else {         
              var formData = $("#searchForm").serialize();
              var trimmedFormData = $.trim(formData);

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "./scripts/search_result.php",
               data: trimmedFormData,
               success: function(data){
                 var popup = $("<div/>", {
                    "data-role": "popup",
                    "class" : "ui-content"
                }).css({
                    "width": $(window).width()*0.6,
                    "height": $(window).height()*0.6
                }).append(closeBtn).append(data);

                // Append it to active page
                $(".ui-page-active").append(popup);

                // Create it and add listener to delete it once it's closed
                // open it
                $("[data-role=popup]").on("popupafterclose", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                }).on("popupafteropen", function () {
                    $(this).popup("reposition", {
                        "positionTo": "window"
                    });
                }).popup({
                    dismissible : false,
                    theme : "b",
                    overlayTheme : "b",
                    transition : "pop"
                }).enhanceWithin().popup("open");    
               }
           });
        }
     });
  });
```

Which basically creates a popup, and a close button, then appends the close button to the popup, the php-request data to the popup, and the popup to the currently active page (from my understanding).